# Is in every set of lebesgue measure $>0$ on $\mathbb R$ a "almost compact" set included

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$.

Let $A \subset \mathbb R$ be a measurable set such that $\lambda(A)>0$.

**Question:**

Can we always find two measurable sets $K_1, K \subset \mathbb R$ such that

- $K_1 \subset A$
- $K \subset \mathbb R$
- $K_1 \subset K$
- $K$ compact
- $\lambda(K_1) = \lambda(K)$
- $\lambda(K_1)>0$

?

**Motivation why $K_1$ and $K$:**

$K_1$ does not have to be compact... Imagine $A=[0,1] \cap \mathbb Q^c$, then there is no compact set included, but $K_1=A$ and $K=[0,1]$ would satisfy the question...

Comment: Is $K$ and $A$ fixed or do you want to find both $K_1$ and $K$?

Comment: Yes both. Sorry I ll edit that.

Comment: Your example does not work, since $A$ is numerable and thus $\lambda(K_1)=0\neq \lambda(K)=1$. Maybe take $A=[0,1]-\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I think you are missing some important restriction (for example $\lambda(K_1)=\lambda(A)$, or $\lambda(K_1)>0$). Otherwise just let $K_1=K=\{x\}$ for some $x\in A$.

Comment: Sorry yes two errors in the question: Of cause $\lambda(K_1) >0$ and i wanted to set $A=[0,1] \cap \mathbb Q^c$... I ll change that

Comment: Why do you have two sets $K$ and $K_1$? If $\lambda(A)\gt0$ then there is a compact set $K\subseteq A$ with $\lambda(K)\gt0$. So just let $K_1=K$.

Comment: Does $\mathbb Q^c$ mean the complement of $\mathbb Q$? Are you aware that the set of irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ contains a compact set of measure $0.999$?

Comment: Yes the complement of $\mathbb Q$...  How to define this compact set?

Comment: Construct an open set $U$ such that $\mathbb Q\subseteq U$ and $\lambda(U)\lt0.001$. (This is easily done using the countability of $\mathbb Q$ and countable additivity of Lebesgue measure.) Then $[0,1]\setminus U$ is a compact set of measure $\gt0.999$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can argue it using the fact Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ is inner regular, hence a measurable set $A$ can be approximated by compact subset from inside.

Comment: As pointed out by Quang Hoang. I forgot to add the restriction $\lambda(K_1)>0$. I have added it now... With this additional restriction your example does NOT work.

Comment: @mimi I have edited my answer.

Comment: This seems to be correct... But this implies that there is a compact set $K \subset [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q^c$ of measure $1-\epsilon$.... But is this really possible?

Comment: @mimi See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271848/inner-regularity-of-lebesgue-measurable-sets)