# Existence of a Borel Set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm reading a proof and in it they construct a set, then just assert they can choose a Borel Set contained in the set with a particular "size". Why can I do this? How do I know something is in there?

The explicit construction is ($(r_n) \in \mathbb{Q}$):

$$V_n = (r_n - \frac{1}{3^{n+1}},r_n + \frac{1}{3^{n+1}}) \\\ W_n = V_n - \bigcup_{k=n+1}^{\infty}V_k$$

They assert there's a Borel set, $A_n$ in $W_n$ with the property $0 < m(A_n) < m(W_n)$.

(The relevant post is here:
[Construction of a Borel set with positive but not full measure in each interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/construction-of-a-borel-set-with-positive-but-not-full-measure-in-each-interval))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (inner) [regularity of Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularity_theorem_for_Lebesgue_measure) implies that a **closed** set is contained in $W_n$ having measure arbitrarily less than the measure of $W_{n}.$ In fact, "closed" can be strengthened to "perfect and nowhere dense". See also [Inner regularity of Lebesgue measurable sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271848/inner-regularity-of-lebesgue-measurable-sets).