# Proof of weak-type inequality for maximal function using only a 'weak'-Vitali lemma

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm studying on 'Real Analysis' of M.Stein & R. Shakarchi, in particular i have a question about the proof propused about the weak-type inequality for maximal function (pag 102-104).
I briefly summarize the reasoning:

**Def(1):** *Let f an integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^d$,
we define its maximal function by
$$f^*(x) = \sup_{x\in B}\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B |f(y)| dy, \hspace{0.25cm} x \in \mathbb{R}^d$$
where the supremum is taken over all balls containing the point x, and m is the Lebesgue measure.*

**Lemma(1):** *Let $\mathscr{B}=\{B_1, B_2, .., B_N\}$ a finite collection of open balls of
$\, \mathbb{R}^d$,
Then there exist a disjoint sub-collection $\{B_{i_{j}}\}_{j=1}^k$ such that:
$$m(\cup_{\ell=1}^N B_\ell) \leq 3^d \sum_{j=1}^k m(B_{i_{j}})$$*

**Thm(weak-type inequality for maximal function):** *Let f an integrable function on $\mathbb{R^d}$,
Let $E_{\alpha} = \{x \in \mathbb{R^d} | f^*(x) > \alpha\}$,
Then $$m(E_\alpha) \leq \frac{3^d}{\alpha} ||f||_{L^1(\mathbb{R^d})}$$*
**Proof of Thm:**

1. It's easy to see that $E_\alpha$ is an open set, so in particular:
   $\forall x\in E_{\alpha} \,\exists B_x, \text{open ball}, x \in B_x : \frac{1}{m(B_x)}\int_{B_x} |f(y)| dy$, in other view:
   $$\text{(A)} \hspace{1cm}m(B_x) < \frac{1}{\alpha} \int_{B_{x}}|f(y)|dy$$
2. We take $K \subset E_{\alpha}$ compact,
   surely $K \subset \cup_{x\in E_{\alpha}} B_x$, since compactness of $K$ there exists a finite sub-cover $K \subset \cup_{i=1}^N B_i$.
3. We use the Lemma(1) on this sub-cover and obtain a disjoint sub-collection $\{B_{i_j}\}_{j=1}^M$.
4. Therefore $m(K) \leq m(\cup_{i=1}^N B_i) \overset{Lemma(1)}{\leq} 3^d \sum_{j=1}^M m(B_{i_j}) \overset{(A)}{\leq} \frac{3^d}{\alpha} \sum_{j=1}^M\int_{B_{i_j}}|f(y)|dy = \frac{3^d}{\alpha} \int_{\cup_{j=1}^M B_{i_j}}|f(y)|dy \leq \frac{3^d}{\alpha} \int_{\mathbb{R^d}}|f(y)|dy = \frac{3^d}{\alpha} ||f||_{L^1(\mathbb{R^d})}$
5. **Since this inequality is true for all compact subset of $E_{\alpha}$ the proof is complete** $\blacksquare$

Now my question:
I cannot understand the 5. step, in particular, i would agree if $m(E_\alpha)< \infty$, because in these condition i can approximate every measurable set with a compact set.
I tryed to proof the finite measure of $E_\alpha$ but without success, i don't know if maybe the fact that $E_\alpha$ is open as well as measurable can help me.

Comment: [Inner regularity of Lebesgue measurable sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/271848/721644)

Answer (score 1):

By the Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem,
$m(E_\alpha)=\lim_{n\to\infty}m(E_\alpha\cap B(0,n))$.
For the same reason, every measurable set can be approximated from the inside with compact sets ( in a measure sense).

Comment: I understand the fist step of you're resoning, however I am not convinced of the second one. In particular: Let be $E_{\alpha}$ a measurable set with $m(E_{\alpha})=\infty$,  let $K \subset E_{\alpha}$ compact. Because $K \subset \mathbb{R^d}$ since thm(Heine-Borel) K is closed and bounded, so $m(K)< C \in \mathbb{R}-\{\infty\}$. Assuming by absurd that $K$ approx $E_{\alpha}$ from inside, in other world assuming that $m(E-K)\leq \epsilon$, then by countable sub-additivity $m(E_{\alpha})=m((E_{\alpha}-K)\cup K) \leq m(E_{\alpha}-K) + m(K) \leq \epsilon + C < \infty$. So we found an absurd.

Comment: I am saying that $m(E)=\sup\{m(K): K \text{ compact }, K\subset E\}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271848/inner-regularity-of-lebesgue-measurable-sets